# Factoring an element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt6]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to know if $1+\sqrt6 $ factors in  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt6]$.

$1+\sqrt6=(a+b\sqrt6)(c+d\sqrt6)$ implies $a^2-6b^2\not=0,c=\frac{a-6b}{a^2-6b^2},a\not=0, d=\frac{a-b}{a^2-6b^2}$

How do I determine if there are integer solutions?

Comment: use the norm $N(a+b\sqrt{6})=a-6b^2$ and its multiplicativity $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$; beware, there are infinitely many units in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{6}]$.

Comment: @cap Try $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. This only has two units.

Answer (score 2):

Use the multiplicativity of the norm : if you define
$N(a+b\sqrt{6})=a^2-6b^2$, then $N(w_1w_2)=N(w_1)N(w_2)$ for any $w_1,w_2$.

So if $1+\sqrt{6}=(a+b\sqrt{6})(c+d\sqrt{6})$, then 
$-5=(a^2-6b^2)(c^2-6d^2)$, so that one of $a^2-6b^2$ or $c^2-6d^2$ is $\pm 1$.
If, say, $a^2-6b^2= \pm 1$, then $a+b\sqrt{6}$ is a unit in ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{6}]$.

So there are no interesting factorizations.

Comment: What do you mean by "so that one of $a^2-6b^2$ is a unit ? Is it possible for both $a+b\sqrt6$ and $c+d\sqrt6$ to be units?

Comment: where is the -5 coming from?

Comment: $-5=(1+\sqrt 6)(1-\sqrt 6)$

Comment: Is that the only factorization of $1+\sqrt6$?

Comment: @cap No. One can show by general theory that if $a+b\sqrt{6}$ is a non-torsion unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$, then the units are precisely $\pm (a+b\sqrt{6})^\mathbb{Z}$. You can check that $5-2\sqrt{6}$ is a unit, and so the only factorizations of $1+\sqrt{6}$ are $1+\sqrt{6}u\cdot u^{-1}$ for any unit $u$--the set of which we've already discussed.